# Proof verification: Prove whether or not every proper subgroup of a nonabelian group is nonabelian.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

> Prove whether or not every proper subgroup of a nonabelian group is nonabelian.

Proof: Counterexample: Let $G=GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ be the general linear group of $2\times 2$ matrices and let $H=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix} \right \}$. Then $H$ is a proper subgroup of the nonabelian group $G$, yet $H$ is abelian. $\square$

Comment: Please ask one question per post - you have two very different questions here. For the first, your proof is not correct: Is $H$ actually a group? For the second, your proof is also incorrect; you haven't shown $ab = ba$.

Comment: Or just take $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow S_3 \times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: The SMALLEST nonabelian group ever gives the counterexample.

Comment: Instead of \begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix} use \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the trivial subgroup is abelian no matter what $G$ is.

But there's more: in fact **every** group (abelian or not) has a nontrivial abelian subgroup. Indeed, let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. Obviously $\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic hence abelian. It is nontrivial if $g$ is. It is proper if $G$ is not of prime order (note that in the case $G$ is of prime order then $\langle g\rangle=G$ hence $G$ is cyclic and abelian).

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct: your $H$ is not a subgroup!  For instance, writing $A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$, $A\in H$ but $A\cdot A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\not\in H$.  (However, there is an even easier example that does work.  Is there some subset of your $H$ which *is* a subgroup?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $m=2n$; the symmetry group of the regular  $n$-gon. The subgroup $Z_n $, the group of rotations is a cyclic subgroup and therefore abelian .